# Наследование от Vector3Int В unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите как можно унаследовать структуру или создать отдельный тип,интерфейс для Vector3Int в unity.

```
// конвертируем кординаты с вектора в другой вектор но в другом формате
Foo ConvertVectorToFoo(Vector3Int vector) 
{
  ...
    return foo
}

Vector3Int ConvertFooToVector(Foo foo)
{
  ...
    return vector 
}
// Метод в который можно передать только правильный формат кординат
Vector3 ConvertFooToWorld(Foo foo)
{
  ...
    return vector 
}

Vector3Int position = getPosition();
ConvertFooToWorld(position) // нельзя так как кординаты в другом формате

Foo foo = ConvertVectorToFoo(position);

ConvertFooToWorld(foo) //так можно так как кординаты в правильном формате
```

Надеюсь я понятно объяснил как собираюсь использовать новый тип, на C# я пишу недавно многое не знаю.

Реальный код который я использую

```
Vector3Int UnityCellToCube(Vector3Int cell)
{
  var yCell = cell.x;
  var xCell = cell.y;
  var x = yCell - (xCell - (xCell & 1)) / 2;
  var z = xCell;
  var y = -x - z;
  return new Vector3Int(x, y, z);
}

Vector3Int CubeToUnityCell(Vector3Int cube)
{
  var x = cube.x;
  var z = cube.z;
  var col = x + (z - (z & 1)) / 2;
  var row = z;

  var res = new Vector3Int(col, row, 0);
  return res;
}

List<Vector3Int> GetNearCubicCellPositions(Vector3Int initPosition)
{
  var cellPositions = new List<Vector3Int>();
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecDr);
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecR);
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecUr);
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecUl);
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecL);
  cellPositions.Add(initPosition + VecDl);
  return cellPositions;
}
List<Vector3Int> GetCubePositionsToCellPositions(List<Vector3Int>cubePositions)
{
  return cubePositions.Select(CubeToUnityCell).ToList();
}

// Проблемное место, сложно понять где кубические кординаты где обычные.
List<Vector3Int> GetNearCellPositions(Vector3Int initPosition)
{
  var initCubePosition = UnityCellToCube(initPosition);
  var cubePositions = GetNearCubicCellPositions(initCubePosition);
  var cellPositions = GetCubePositionsToCellPositions(cubePositions);
  return cellPositions;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы выкинули возможно полезный для понимания вопроса код? Почему вы решили, что он не имеет отношения к делу? Тем более, если вы сами же утверждаете, что многого не знаете. Покажите реальный код вместе с Фу. А так же объясните, зачем именно этот Фу вам нужен, может на самом деле и не нужен вовсе. Не жалейте букв, они бесплатные, пишите как можно подробнее. А пока ответ "структура не может быть унаследована ни от чего, она может только реализовать интерфейс".

Comment: @aepot дополнил реальным кодом

Comment: Теперь объясните, что он делает и в чем заключается задача, которую вы решаете.

Comment: Ты пытаешься между cell и cube, потому, что они оба Vector3Int... Вот только почему cell не Vector2Int?

Comment: У меня есть хексагональное поле. и 2 типа кординат стандартные для сетки unity и кубические.
во многих алгоритмы проще использовать кубические кординаты.
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#conversions
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#neighbors

Comment: @Yaroslav https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html

Потому что я работаю с Vector3Int. получаю я кординаты с сетки в виде Vector3Int

Comment: Я хочу иметь тип(структуру,класс,интерфейс) Vector3IntCube который будет точной копией Vector3Int, Который я укажу в методах и буду точно знать где у меня кубические, а где стандартные координаты ячейки

Comment: Делать дубликат класса - это не то чем следует заниматься в C#. Тем более родной вектор имеет аппаратное ускорение при вычислениях, а то что вы хотите сделать - не будет его иметь. Плохая затея.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще заниматься подобным плохо, но:

```
public struct Vector3IntCube
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Vector3IntCube (int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public override bool Equals (object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static Vector3IntCube zero => new Vector3IntCube(0, 0, 0);

    public static Vector3IntCube operator + (Vector3IntCube a, Vector3IntCube b) => new Vector3IntCube(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y, a.z+b.z);
    public static Vector3IntCube operator - (Vector3IntCube a, Vector3IntCube b) => new Vector3IntCube(a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y, a.z-b.z);

    public static Vector3IntCube operator * (Vector3IntCube a, int b) => new Vector3IntCube(a.x*b, a.y*b, a.z*b);

    public static bool operator == (Vector3IntCube a, Vector3IntCube b) => a.Equals(b);
    public static bool operator != (Vector3IntCube a, Vector3IntCube b) => a.Equals(b) == false;


    public static implicit operator Vector3Int (Vector3IntCube value) => new Vector3Int(value.x, value.y, value.z);
    public static implicit operator Vector3IntCube (Vector3Int value) => new Vector3IntCube(value.x, value.y, value.z);
}
```

`implicit operator` позволяет писать так:

```
Vector3Int v3i = new Vector3Int(1, 2, 3);
Vector3IntCube v3ic = v3i;
v3i = v3ic;
if (v3i == (Vector3Int)v3ic) {}
```